# Snow until the end of the page

Tags: javascript

I have a script of snow for the site, I took it from [this site](http://www.peters1.dk/webtools/javascript/sne.php). As you can see, the snow does not go the bottom of the page. How can I make it go to the bottom?

Source code:

```
var SNOW_Time;
var SNOW_dx, SNOW_xp, SNOW_yp;
var SNOW_am, SNOW_stx, SNOW_sty;
var i, SNOW_Browser_Width = $(document).width(), SNOW_Browser_Height = $(document).height();

SNOW_dx = new Array();
SNOW_xp = new Array();
SNOW_yp = new Array();
SNOW_am = new Array();
SNOW_stx = new Array();
SNOW_sty = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < SNOW_no; ++i) {
    SNOW_dx[i] = 0;
    SNOW_xp[i] = Math.random() * (SNOW_Browser_Width - 50);
    SNOW_yp[i] = Math.random() * SNOW_Browser_Height;
    SNOW_am[i] = Math.random() * 20;
    SNOW_stx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random() / 10;
    SNOW_sty[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();
    if (i == 0) document.write("<\div id=\"SNOW_flake" + i + "\" style=\"position: absolute; z-index: " + i + "; visibility: visible; top: 15px; left: 15px; width: " + SNOW_Width + "; height: " + SNOW_Height + "; background: url('" + SNOW_Picture + "') no-repeat;\"><\/div>");
    else document.write("<\div id=\"SNOW_flake" + i + "\" style=\"position: absolute; z-index: " + i + "; visibility: visible; top: 15px; left: 15px; width: " + SNOW_Width + "; height: " + SNOW_Height + "; background: url('" + SNOW_Picture + "') no-repeat;\"><\/div>");
}

function SNOW_Weather() {

    for (i = 0; i < SNOW_no; ++i) {
        SNOW_yp[i] += SNOW_sty[i];

        if (SNOW_yp[i] > SNOW_Browser_Height) {
            SNOW_xp[i] = Math.random() * (SNOW_Browser_Width - SNOW_am[i] - 30);
            SNOW_yp[i] = 0;
            SNOW_stx[i] = 0.02 + Math.random() / 10;
            SNOW_sty[i] = 0.7 + Math.random();
        }

        SNOW_dx[i] += SNOW_stx[i];

        document.getElementById("SNOW_flake" + i).style.top = SNOW_yp[i] + "px";
        document.getElementById("SNOW_flake" + i).style.left = SNOW_xp[i] + SNOW_am[i] * Math.sin(SNOW_dx[i]) + "px";
    }

    SNOW_Time = setTimeout("SNOW_Weather()", 10);

}

SNOW_Weather();
```

Comment: I see you have unaccepted my answer. Was there something you wanted me to add to make it satisfying to you?

Comment: sorry, accidentally hit the button ... :)

Comment: Haha thanks, I was wondering what was wrong with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's determined by the variable `SNOW_Browser_Height`. `$(document).height()` doesn't return the proper height. You could use this instead:

```
document.body.getClientRects()[0].height
```

Comment: @MaksudAbdurahmanov welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer solves your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.